# How is Ilist.Add implemented in CollectionBase class?

Tags: c#

What I have known is that a class that derived from a CollectionBase class can use List.Add() directly, which List is a properties that return an instance of CollectionBase itself. But I am confused since I can't find any implementation of the Ilist.Add method in the CollectionBase class.

I thought that the class would have some implementation like this in order to use that method but I can't find one.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist.add?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_IList_Add_System_Object_

The Add method is in "explicit interface implementation" but I don't know why it has something to do with the actual implementation

For your convenience:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.collectionbase?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/collectionbase.cs,132

You can see the implementation in line 132.

Comment: Line numbers are links on Reference Source. Those links go directly to the [specific line](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/collectionbase.cs,132). No need to then have to tell people which line to go to.

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot! May I ask is there a reason why they choose to hide the implementation on the  documentation?

Comment: @YawenZhang Not sure why you think they hide it. In the link you posted, you can see the method at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.collections.collectionbase?view=net-5.0#explicit-interface-implementations and also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.collectionbase.system-collections-ilist-add?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_CollectionBase_System_Collections_IList_Add_System_Object_ is present

Comment: Sorry man what I am looking for is something like this and I don't know if i am stupid cuz I cant find it in the link: int IList.Add(Object value) {
            OnValidate(value);
            OnInsert(InnerList.Count, value);
            int index = InnerList.Add(value);
            try {
                OnInsertComplete(index, value);
            }
            catch {
                InnerList.RemoveAt(index);
                throw;
            }
            return index;
        }

Comment: @YawenZhang If you're looking for the implementation (source code), then look at the source code I posted in the answer. The docs do not include source code usually - only code samples how classes are meant to be used.

Comment: Ok I got it, thank you again for your patience, I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: @YawenZhang feel free to mark it as answer if it answers your question ;-)